# How to understand Tensorflow CPU usage (process killed by out-of-memory handler)

Tags: python, tensorflow

I used to train a DNN with relatively small training and validation sets, but I now need to switch to 10 times bigger sets and this is causing memory issues that I do not fully understand.

### How I load the data

Before switching to the bigger sets, I made some checks in order to know how much memory my training is consuming. My data is saved into `.h5` files, each of them containing 5000 training examples and being `4.5G` in size. From them, I load my training examples and my labels doing the following:

```
for n in range(nfiles) : # loop on input .h5 files, open n-th file, extract what you need, close                                                                                    
    if n == 0 :
        with h5.File(data_path+"/"+file_name+str(n+1)+".h5","r") as input_h5 :
            examples = np.array( input_h5['data'][:,:,:nfeats] )
            labels = np.array( input_h5['labels'][:,:,:nswd] )

    else :
        with h5.File(data_path+"/"+file_name+str(n+1)+".h5","r") as input_h5:
            examples = np.concatenate( [examples, input_h5['data'][:,:,:nfeats]], axis = 0 )
            labels = np.concatenate( [labels, input_h5['labels'][:,:,:nswd]], axis = 0 )
```

I do this both for the training and validation sets, so I eventually load 4 `np.arrays`. Since I load the data from 5 files for training and 1 file for validation, and since `nfeats == 20` and `nswd == 15`, when I compute their sizes by using `np.nbytes` method I get

```
examples_train.shape(): (25000, 4000, 20)
examples_train size (GB): 8.0
labels_train.shape(): (25000, 4000, 15)
labels_train size (GB): 6.0
examples_val.shape(): (5000, 4000, 20)
examples_val size (GB): 1.6
labels_val.shape(): (5000, 4000, 15)
labels_val size (GB): 1.2
```

### My questions

1. If I add the sizes that I just posted above, I get that the total amount of data that I need for the training has a size of `16.8 GB`. If I scale this for 10 times, I get `168 GB`. I can run my training on a slurm cluster with up to 9 CPUs, each having 40GB of RAM.
   **EDIT:** Let me give more details on this part, as requested by Dr. Snoopy in a comment. In my slurm script I am doing

```
#SBATCH --ntasks=1 
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=9 
#SBATCH --mem-per-cpu=40000
```

This should be way enough, but it turns out it is not the case, as I cannot load my files and the process is killed by the out-of-memory handler **before the training even starts**. I am aware that the backpropagation step in the training needs to save information on RAM in order to perform the weights update, but the training did not start, so this should not be the issue. Does my reasoning here hold? If so, am I missing some important pieces?

2. I think the way I deal with the input files is correct, I should be opening just one file at a time, store what I need, and close it. So I don't expect this to cause memory issues. Am I correct here?
3. So, if what I describe in points 1. and 2. holds true, what is actually happening? Why does my process get killed? The picture seems inconsistent to me, but I guess I am missing something.

Thanks a lot for your time!

Cheers,

F.

Comment: What do you mean 9 CPUs with 40 GB of RAM? Are you talking about nodes each having 40 GB of RAM? Because its not the same to have individual nodes and one node with 40 * 9 GB of RAM.

Comment: Hi @Dr.Snoopy, thanks for your comment. I am not 100% sure, as I find the slurm jargon a bit confusing. Here's what I am doing:
`#SBATCH --ntasks=1`
`#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=9`
`#SBATCH --mem-per-cpu=40000`